# How to make binding work on additional parameter with a Get request

Tags: binding, asp.net-core-mvc

My model has property

```cs
public int SelectedContactId { get; set; }
```

The view has a dropdown, and on changing selection it refreshes the view:

```html
<select asp-for="SelectedContactId" 
    asp-items="Model.Contacts" 
    class="form-control ddlContractorContacts bg-light" 
    onchange="location.reload(true)">
</select>
```

The HttpGet Edit() action method is called:

```cs
// GET: Contractors/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? contractorId, int SelectedContactId)
```

But `SelectedContactId` is not bound, and I cannot figure out how it can be done.

P.S. If I use `[FromBody]` attribute before `int SelectedContactId`, I get an error on the first loading the page: HTTP ERROR 415.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, from reading your comment

```cs
// GET: Contractors/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? contractorId, int SelectedContactId)
```

it looks like the contractor id is 5 and it will be always there with the URL since you're editing a contractor. So you should change it to

```cs
// GET: Contractors/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int Id, int SelectedContactId)
```

to take advantage of MVC default route mapping - the integer after / should automatically bind to `Id`.

And then I think your `SelectedContactId` should be marked as optional, because when you first land on the edit page, there shouldn't be any selected contact. And you want to automatically bind the selected contact as additional parameter on the URL as soon as the user picks a contact. That's what you want to accomplish right?

If that's the case, you should change `SelectedContactId` to optional:

```cs
// GET: Contractors/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int Id, int? SelectedContactId)
```

Now let's get to the point. There are many ways to manipulate query parameters. Some of them are:

1. Submit a GET form
2. Use JavaScript to manually append inputs to the URL

Here I am showing you the #1 - Submit a GET form.

### Submit a GET form

If you want the server to get the input selections on the view, you need submit the `<form />` that contains all the inputs.

Whenever the user makes the selection and hits the submit button, the form will send the input data back to the server. And your MVC will bind the request to your action's parameters.

Using *JavaScript* `location.reload(true)` will only refresh the current page. It doesn't send the inputs back to the server.

#### View Model

```cs
public class EditContractorViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Contact")]
    public int? SelectedContactId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

```cs
public class ContractorController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Edit(int id, int? selectedContactId)
    {
        // In theory, you need to take the id and look that up in your persistent storage
        // and then you build up the view model and pass it back to the View

        var vm = new EditContractorViewModel
        {
            SelectedContactId = selectedContactId,
            Contacts = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem("Contact 1", "1"),
                new SelectListItem("Contact 2", "2"),
                new SelectListItem("Contact 3", "3"),
                new SelectListItem("Contact 4", "4"),
                new SelectListItem("Contact 5", "5")
            }
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

#### View

```html
<!-- The View -->
@model EditContractorViewModel

<form asp-area="" asp-controller="ContractorController" asp-action="Edit"
    method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="SelectedContactId"></label>
        <select asp-for="SelectedContactId" 
            asp-items="Model.Contacts" 
            class="form-control ddlContractorContacts bg-light">
            <option value="">- select -</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### Result

First landing on the page:

[image]

Select a contact and hit submit:

[image]

If you want the form to be automatically submitted on the dropdown change, you can get rid of the submit button on the view and write some *JavaScripts* to submit the form manually:

```js
$(function() {
    $('select.ddlContractorContacts').change(function() {
        let $form = $(this).closest('form');

        $form.submit();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the second solution you suggested, but for some reason it does not come to the controller's action method. Also, if I understand correctly, it would call the Post method, but I need Get, to reload the page based on the new dropdown selection. Is it not possible?

Comment: @DavidShochet: no, it wouldn't call the Post method. Remember, the form is setup as "GET", i.e., method="get", it will call its "GET" method. `$form.submit()` will just submit the form. It doesn't care whether the form is doing "GET" or "POST". I am working on an update to try to help you understand what I am saying. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thank you David. Just wanted to mentioned that I need Post too for saving the data. Just not on changing the dropdown selection.

Comment: @DavidShochet: Awww too late lol I've updated my answer. And for saving data, that should be another post.

Comment: No, I have no problems (so far) saving data. Just did not want your solution to contradict my goals. I did mentioned that refreshing the page on dropdown selection change should use get, but I did not say post should not be used at all.

Comment: @DavidShochet: then you have to use javascript to manually append query parameters to the URL. Your title of your OP didn't mention anything on the POST / saving so I didn't take that as consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `location.reload(true)`,it will always redirect to `/Contractors/Edit/5` and your `SelectedContactId` on Edit action will always be 0 since you do not pass the selected Id in query string or somewhere else.

A simple way is that you could pass the Id using query string like `/Contractors/Edit/5?SelectedContactId=1`.

Refer to below code of the view:

```
<select asp-for="SelectedContactId"
        asp-items="Model.Contacts"
        id="mySelectedContactId"
        class="form-control ddlContractorContacts bg-light"
        onchange="reload()"></select>

@section  Scripts{ 
<script>
    function reload() {
        var selectedContactId = document.getElementById("mySelectedContactId").value;
        var url = window.location.href.split(/[?#]/)[0];    

        url += '?SelectedContactId=' + selectedContactId

        window.location.href = url;
     }
</script>
}
```